# Not able to set custom prefab as a mesh to Particle system

Tags: unity, particles

I am extremely new to Unity and trying my hands on the Particle System and facing an unusual problem. I don't know whether it is a bug or a legit logic, but in below picture / scene, I am not able to add the custom bullet prefab as the mesh of the particle system. In the suggestion window of the mesh, it is only showing Unity's pre-built 3D objects like Cube, Sphere... but not the prefab I created ...
[image]

Why is that happening?

Comment: A "prefab" is not a "mesh". From the preview in your screenshot, it looks like your bullet prefab uses a sphere mesh that's been stretched — is that accurate? Or did you import a custom mesh for it that's not showing up here?

Comment: No I haven't imported any . I have stretched the the sphere...that's right. But then how to use custom "figures" in the Particle System. Is there any way out?

Comment: Are you asking "How can I use a spherical mesh in my particle system, and stretch it along one axis"?

Comment: No. For example I 'am having a custom object that has been modeled in some other software (say Blender), if I import in into Unity, how can I use it as a thing that fires from particle system?

Comment: That would be a mesh, no? Did you try it? Where specifically did you run into difficultly importing a mesh from Blender and using it in a particle system?

Comment: This is the exact error I'm getting :                                                                       
Particle system meshes will only work with exactly one (1) sub mesh
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Comment: Try editing your question to show 1. How you've built your mesh in Blender, 2. How you've imported it into Unity, and 3. That error message. It should be possible for someone reading your question to reproduce the same problem, without asking you any follow-up questions.